# Defining displacement in purely geometric terms (without using analytic geometry or coordinates)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, vector-spaces

Displacements are normally defined as vectors (e.g. Wikipedia states ["a displacement is a vector whose length is the shortest distance from the initial to the final position of a point P undergoing motion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(geometry))).  However, it would seem to me that, like points and lines, displacements should be defineable in purely geometric - that is, Euclidean - terms.

Is there such a definition for displacements?

Continuing that, I'd seek to prove that:

- Displacements can be composed, and that composition of displacements meets all the requirements for a group (an abelian group, in fact)
- Displacements can be multiplied by any $n \in \mathbb N$ via induction over repeated displacement; by $0$ (the null displacement); by $-1$ (the displacement from $P$ to $Q$ maps to the displacement from $Q$ to $P$); and hence by any $z \in \mathbb Z$
- This can be further extended to $\mathbb Q$ by defining $1/n \cdot PQ$ as the displacement that, when repeated $n$ times, goes from $P$ to $Q$.  Extending to $\mathbb R$ should be possible via limits, though I'm not sure how to define a Cauchy sequence of displacements (again, using only Euclidean terms)
- The above gives a vector space of displacements in purely Euclidean terms

Furthermore, assuming that the Euclidean space has a well defined notion of *length*, I'd define a norm $||PQ||$ as the length of line segment $\overline{PQ}$, seeking to prove that this definition is consistent (if displacement $PQ = $ displacement $RS$, then length $\overline {PQ} = $ length $\overline {RS}$) and meets the norm criteria.  Likewise, assuming that the Euclidean space has a well defined notion of *angle measure*, I'd use it to define the dot product and show it is well defined and an inner product.

All of the above can, I believe, be done in purely Euclidean terms, once displacements are defined that way.  (Of course, the results would be isometric to $\mathbb R^n$, but my goal is to construct the system directly, without relying on that isomorphism.)

**Questions:**

1. What is the Euclidean definition of a displacement?
2. Is the plan I outline above correct and complete? Is it missing anything?
3. Are there standard references or definitions for the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the language of functions is permitted then one might have a definition along the lines of the following.

A translation $T$ is a bijection mapping points $P$ of a geometrical figure $F$ onto points $P^\prime$ of a geometrical figure $F^\prime$ with the property that for every pair of points $A,B\in F$ it is the case that $AA^\prime B^\prime B $ is a parallelogram.

One could specify that the identity map and  any map of a singleton set onto a singleton set are translations.

Comment: Great definition.  Can this be extended to identify when two translations are orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Well, I suppose $T_1\perp T_2$ when for $A\in F$, $AA'\perp AA"$.